# what does anonymous-*-* mean in this bash command?

Tags: bash, shell, glob, ls

I know what the ls -d does but I am confused about `anonymous-*-* |\` part, can someone please explain this

```
ls -d $data/anonymous-*-* |\
```

assuming $data is a directory name

Comment: It's just an ordinary filename wildcard. `*` matches any sequence of characters

Comment: So this requires that there's at least one more `-` after `anonymous-` in the filenames.

Comment: The vertical bar (`|`) means the output from `ls` is being piped to the following command and the backslash means the command continues on the next line.

Comment: Although technically the backslash is not required if the line ends with `|` (or `&&` or `||`). The [Google shell style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html) recommends [a particular style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html#pipelines) for pipelines spanning multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [bash globbing](https://linuxhint.com/bash_globbing_tutorial/), and is really useful for matching filenames and text. The `*` wildcard matches any text at all. So `anonymous-*-*` would match any filenames that begin with `anonymous-`, and have another dash `-` somewhere after that in the filename.

Comment: Thank you for the help. 
This is the whole command, so I am guessing inside the $data folder the anonymous-*-* files are getting created in a previous step.


    ls -d $data/anonymous-*-* |\
     awk '
     BEGIN {i=0}
     { anon_users[++i] = $0; }
     END { for (j in anon_users) {printf("anonymous%04d %s\n", j, anon_users[j]);}}' |\
     sort -k1 > $data_local/anon.map